# Do not run a python script again within a specific time (e.g. 1 hour)

Tags: python, timer, notifications

I'm using this python script:
[LINK](https://gist.github.com/JonnyWong16/1b1b02536e25002daf678946f513b950)

It's working great so far.
But now I would like to optimize it, because sometimes it's happening that the script will be executed 2-3 times within 10-20 minutes, because it will always run if there are 3 streams or more (e.g. a 4. stream will be started --> notification will be send again or also if a user decide to cancel this stream and watch another movie --> The script will run again!)

I have tried to use `time.sleep` but that is not working. I would like to have it like this:

If the program will be executed,it shouldn't be run again within the next 60 minutes.

What do I need to use / code here?

Thanks for help!

Thank you for the Tip, my code does look like this now (can you maybe check?):

** code section ** = my code which I have merged inside the existing script.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Description:  Send a PlexPy notification when the total 
#               number of streams exceeds a threshold.
# Author:       /u/SwiftPanda16
# Requires:     requests
# PlexPy script trigger:    Playback start
# PlexPy script arguments:  {streams}

import requests
import sys
**import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta**


### EDIT SETTINGS ###

PLEXPY_URL = 'xx.xxx.xx:8181'
PLEXPY_APIKEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AGENT_ID = 14  # The PlexPy notifier agent id found here: https://github.com/JonnyWong16/plexpy/blob/master/API.md#notify
NOTIFY_SUBJECT = 'test'  # The notification subject
NOTIFY_BODY = 'Test'
STREAM_THRESHOLD = 3

**### time management ###
one_hour_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=60)
filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime("timestamp.txt"))
if filetime < one_hour_ago:**

### CODE BELOW ###
    def main():
        try:
            streams = int(sys.argv[1])
        except:
            print("Invalid PlexPy script argument passed.")
            return

        if streams >= STREAM_THRESHOLD:
            print("Number of streams exceeds {threshold}.".format(threshold=STREAM_THRESHOLD))
            print("Sending PlexPy notification to agent ID: {agent_id}.".format(agent_id=AGENT_ID))

            params =   {'apikey': PLEXPY_APIKEY,
                        'cmd': 'notify',
                        'agent_id': AGENT_ID,
                        'subject': NOTIFY_SUBJECT,
                        'body': NOTIFY_BODY}

            r = requests.post(PLEXPY_URL.rstrip('/') + '/api/v2', params=params)
            **os.getcwd()
            open ('timestamp.txt', 'w')**
        else:
            print("Number of streams below {threshold}.".format(threshold=STREAM_THRESHOLD))
            print("No notification sent.")
            return


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()



**else:
    pass**
```

Comment: easy way: just create a dummy file every time you run, so next you run, first check the time in the file? if less than 1 hour, then do not run

Comment: Thanks, can you check my edited code? Tests looks great so far.

Answer (score 1):

Have the script write a timestamp to an external file and check that file at startup.

Here is an example:

```
import time

def script_has_run_recently(seconds):
    filename = 'last-run-time.txt'
    current_time = int(time.time())
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            last_run = int(f.read().strip())
    except (IOError, ValueError) as e:
        last_run = 0
    if last_run + seconds > current_time:
        return True
    else:
        with open(filename, 'wt') as f:
            f.write(str(current_time))
        return False


def main():
    print('running the main function.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    seconds = 3600  # one hour in seconds
    if script_has_run_recently(seconds):
        print('you need to wait before you can run this again')
    else:
        main()
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I was able to handle it. I have edited my post, can you maybe please check? Thanks.